# TortoiseSVN merging a branch to trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is a continuation of this question: [TortoiseSVN merging branch to trunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476475/tortoisesvn-merging-branch-to-trunk/18479794)
If the original question should just be edited, please let me know and I'll do that.

Here's the current situation.

Have a project with a working copy on my PC that was all up to date. I created a new branch based on that and switched my working copy over to this new branch.

Since doing that another developer checked in some changes to the trunk, and I've made some changes to the branch. I don't think we've changed the same files so we should be good as far as any conflicts go.

I want to merge my changes back into the trunk.

I select merge, and then select merge a range of revision. URL to merge from i have the trunk selected. Range is blank. When i do a test merge it appears to be adding every file ever added into the project - it's certainly adding way more files then have been changes since i split off from the trunk. It's doing hundreds of files when there should just be 10 or 20 files changed.

Should i instead select the range of revisions that the other developer checked in to trunk? Or should i instead be selecting 'merge two different trees' ? If I try that and try doing a test merge from trunk to my branch i get a conflict. If i try doing from my branch to trunk, it looks like it works. Although I would then want to push everything back to trunk at that point since I've made some fixes in my branch that i want to include in the trunk before I proceed with any more changes in the branch.

**edit**: a little more detail to help clarity the current setup

My working copy was previously part of the trunk. I used tortoise to create a new branch and switched my working copy to that branch. So the project looks like:
/project/branches/mybranch

trunk looks like
/project/trunk

Another dev checked some changes into trunk, and i've checked some changes into mybranch. I want to merge all those changes back into trunk before i do any more work on mybranch. When i view the log for mybranch, there's only 3 checkins; 153, 154 and 159 (and 153 is just the creation of the branch)
when i view the log for trunk there are 4 since it was split from the trunk: 155-158

There should be no conflicts as we did not work on the same files.

If i try to merge FROM mybranch and do not specify a revision range, it appears to be adding every file in the project. i.e. i do a test merge and it's showing hundreds of files as added.

If I do a test merge FROM trunk and specify revision 155-158 that looks like it will merge all the changes from trunk into my working copy. I suppose if i do that i can then check everything into mybranch at which point i just need to figure out how to merge everything back into trunk.

All of the above was done using 'merge a range of revisions'.

If i try doing 'merge two different trees' and try merging FROM trunk to mybranch (with head revision) i get a conflict.

If i try merging FROM mybranch to trunk, it looks like it works.

From what i have seen, it looks like doing the tree merge from mybranch to trunk is what i want to do. I'm just not certain since so far i've been told to do otherwise.

I want everything pushed into trunk. I plan on making large changes to the code in mybranch which will break the project until it's finished, which is why i want trunk to be up to date before i start on that, in case i need to fix any existing code.

**edit2**: when i do a merge range of revisions and select mybranch as the url to merge from, this is what shows up in the tortoise window as the command:
Command: Merging revisions 1-HEAD of /branches/mybranch into C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject, respecting ancestry, Test Only

My working copy is already on mybranch. So to me this sounds like it's merging mybranch into my working copy, which is already part of mybranch, so basically it's merging mybranch into itself?

Merging FROM trunk is the only thing that would make sense to me. And if do merge FROM trunk and select the revision range that the other dev checked in, the output seems correct. At that point then I would just need to then merge it all back into trunk.

Command: Merging revisions 154-158 of /trunk into C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myproject, respecting ancestry, Test Only

The revision numbers that matter are:

trunk: 155-158 - these are the revisions the other dev checked into trunk

mybranch: 153, 154 and 159. 153 is the creation of the branch. 154 and 159 are actual file changes that need to be merged into the trunk.

The other command i just tried which also seems like it will do what i want is if i merge from mybranch to trunk and specify revision 154 or 159 under FROM and revision 152 under TO (trunk). I've never tried working with anything other then the current revision though so I'm not exactly sure what happens if i merge with a revision a few numbers back.

Command: Merging from /branches/mybranch, revision 154 to /trunk, revision 152 into C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myproject, respecting

appreciate any help on clarifying the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are the paths correct and at the same depth in your project/solution hierarchy? That is, if you have `svn://example.com/foo/trunk/project/` and `svn://example.com/foo/mybranch/` to make sure to select `svn://example.com/foo/trunk/project/` and NOT `svn://example.com/foo/trunk/` for the merge URL

Answer (score 8):

> URL to merge from i have the trunk selected.

If you want merge back to `trunk`, then the *URL to merge from* is your `branch`. You merge from the repository-version of the `branch` to the local copy of trunk. When the merge is finished you check in the trunk.

***Update***: For all who don’t want read entire comments bellow: As *merk* mentioned in the comments, it is necessary to have a checked out copy of the trunk.

Comment: when i do that, if i dont specify a revision range, it appears as though it's adding in every file from the project. There's only 20 or so files that have been changed between trunk and my branch. But when i do as you suggest, it's adding in hundreds of files. If i select the revisions i checked in and then do a test merge, nothing really gets updated. I'm going to update my original question with a little more detail to try and make it clear what the current setup is.

Comment: There is nothing special in what you want "merge a range of revision" is fine and merge branch to trunk is everyday business. That he wants add hundreds of files seem to be a configuration problem of your svn-client (tortoise).

Comment: I'm not really sure what would be wrong with tortoise. I haven't done anything unusual with it. And it's been working fine up to this point. I think there's just some mis-communication between us as to how this should be done. For example, if as you suggest in url to merge from i select the trunk, how does it know WHERE to merge it back? My working copy is part of the branch. So if it tell it to merge FROM mybranch, how does it know where to merge it to? I will update the question again with some additional detail

Comment: To Sum it up: When I want to merge a branch to trunk (1) I check out the trunk, (2) merge branch ("URL to Merge From") in the local copy of trunk, (3) resolve all conflicts, (4) check in trunk, (5) go for a coffee. This works fine and I have done this many times successfully. In this case "trunk-perspective" is the key.

Comment: yeah finally got it working - i didn't realize i needed to check out a copy of trunk. It's very counter-intuitive to my way of thinking that i have to check out an entire copy of the code just so i can check in a handful files that it actually already has (in the branch). I thought i'd be able to do all this within SVN itself. Seems like a very inefficient way of doing things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is the SVN-Way ;). Nice to here that I could help you. Would be nice if can accept answer.

Comment: i gave it an upvote - only reason i didnt accept it as an answer is it wasn't exactly the answer. i do appreciate the help - but if it's not actually the answer, i don't think i should mark it as an answer, just so if anyone else has the same question, they don't go down the wrong path because something was marked as the answer when it really wasnt. Hope that makes sense, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can do what ever you want ;) - Thanks for upvote

Comment: @merk I was suffering from the same problem and I actually came here due to the link in your first question :) . I strongly recommend though you post another answer on this question stating the actual solution so others won't have to read through the comments under Micha's answer and guess about the details ;) - you can also accept your own solution - to mark it as the definite answer.

Comment: I'm with Zainodis although @Micha could edit their answer to include the info they gave in the comments and then it could be marked as the answer. Till then SO will consider this question unanswered when really it is.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I'm with you. The question should have an accepted answer. If it is my or a new one doesn't really matter. As for me I have had edit my answer.