# Tortoise SVN merge two branches

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch

i'm trying to merge two branches with tortoise SVN.
Both branches have been changed since they diverged.
If i merge them, only the changes of one of them obtain and those of the other will be overwritten.
But i want the latest change of every file (We have not been working in the same files).

I tried the option "Merge two different trees" and entered the two branches in "From:" and "To:".
I took the Head Revision on both.
I left everything else to default (Merge depth: Working Copy, Compare whitespaces, everything else unchecked)

Comment: Have both branches a common ancestry branch/trunk?

Comment: Yes. The first one is the Trunk, and the other is a branch from it.

Comment: Merge from (any) branch to trunk (branch reintegration )isn't "Merge two different trees" and **never** must be it. Try to read at least once `svn help merge` and TortoiseSVN help for merge!!!

Comment: Please look at the highest voted answer in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308584/merge-two-branches-using-tortoise-svn. I think that should be enough for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two branches using tortoise SVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308584/merge-two-branches-using-tortoise-svn)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the `From URL` option, you should specify the branch to which you want to merge.

For example, assume that there are 2 branches, branch `A` and branch `B`, and you want to merge branch `B` to branch `A`.

- In TortoiseSVN, click on `Merge` option and then select `Merge two
  different trees` option.
- In the `From URL`, please mention URL of
  branch `A` and in the `To URL`, mention URL of branch `B`.

This should merge branch `B` to branch `A` without losing any files.

Reference: found this statement [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)

Comment: Well that seems reversed.

Comment: Seemed to me as well, but found this statement [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) "In the From: field enter the full folder URL of the trunk. This **may sound wrong**, but remember that the trunk is the start point to which you want to add the branch changes."

Answer (score 11):

Merging in Subversion is always done *locally*. The branch you want to merge to should be checked out with a clean checkout. That is, it should be up to date with no local changes. You then merge the other branch into it and commit your changes.

A *Merge* is not a duplicate of a particular branch. Merging is usually a three way operation. You have the branch you're merging into (called *yours*) the branch you're merging from (called *theirs*), and the last common ancestor (LCA). That last one is important.

If a change took place on *your* branch, it's not touched during the merge process. The merge algorithm knows this because there's a difference between *yours* and the LCA. If there is difference between the LCA and *theirs*, that's considered for a change.

If I understand you have:

- `branch1` was taken from trunk.
- `branch2` was taken from `branch1`.

What are you trying to merge? Do you want to merge both `branch1` and `branch2` into trunk. This should be possible if you *copied* `trunk` into `branch1` through Subversion and *copied* `branch1` into `branch2` through Subversion. This way, Subversion knows that the two branches are related in their history.

If you created the branch, used Windows to copy the files, and added the files, you have no history between the two branches, and merging is more difficult.

Is it okay to merge the changes of `branch2` into `branch1`? If so, I'd do something like this:

- Checkout `branch2`
- Merge `branch1` into `branch2` and commit those changes. `branch2` will have all the changes in `branch1`.
- Checkout `trunk`
- Merge `branch2` into `trunk`. Trunk will now have all the changes in both `branch1` and `branch2`.

Answer (score 1):

"*Merge two different trees*" option is useful when you're trying to make one branch look exactly like another branch.

If instead you want your output branch to contain changes from both the branches, you should use the "*Merge a range of revisions*" option.

**Steps to use the Merge a range of revisions option:**

*Note: `output branch` refers to the branch you want to merge your changes into.
While `input branch` refers to the branch whose changes you want to merge in the output branch*

1. Take a clean working copy of the `output branch`
2. Open the TortoiseSVN merge wizard (TortoiseSVN > Merge), and select the "Merge a range of revisions" option
3. In the URL to merge from field, enter the `input branch`
4. In the Revision range to merge field, select 'all revisions' if you want to merge all the revisions of the `input branch`. If you want to merge specific revisions only, select 'specific range' and use the 'Show log' button to choose the revisions. TortoiseSVN is smart in this regard, and any revision that has already been merged will be greyed out and marked with an *Already merged* icon
5. Select the Merge options on the next screen. The default options are good enough
6. Use the Merge button to perform the merge. Conflicts (if any) will pop up, asking you to choose a resolution
7. After resolving all conflicts, commit the changes to your `output branch`

[image: Figure 4.56. The Merge Wizard - Select Revision Range]

For further details refer to [TortoiseSVN Docs on Merging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)